# save json in array

Tags: jquery, ajax

How can I convert this json

```
{
    "dates": [
        "12-10-2012",
        "12-11-2012",
        "13-11-2012",
        "22-11-2012",
        "23-11-2012",
        "2-12-2012"
    ]
}
```

into an array like this

```
var array = ["12-10-2012", "12-11-2012", "13-11-2012", "22-11-2012", "23-11-2012", "2-12-2012"]
```

Comment: Have you tried anything?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What you want to do is called parsing. Some browsers, like Chrome have this native function

```
 var obj = JSON.parse(string)
```

But if you use jQuery, you can use

```
var obj = $.parseJSON(string)
```

This will give you an object. You can then do

```
obj.dates
```

Answer (score 1):

What you have is an object that contains the array. All you have to do is get the value of the object using key `dates`.

Assuming a var defined for data like below,

```
var data = {
    "dates": [
        "12-10-2012",
        "12-11-2012",
        "13-11-2012",
        "22-11-2012",
        "23-11-2012",
        "2-12-2012"
    ]
}
```

then `data['dates']` will return you that array.

Answer (score 0):

just use the dates variable itself

```
var json = { ... your json ...}
var array = json.dates;
```

the dates property inside your json is an array already

Answer (score 0):

Parse the JSON and get the `dates` property:

```
var array = $.parseJSON(theJsonString).dates;
```